# TimeTrigger Exception "Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor."

Tags: c#, azure-functions

When I run my azure function with TimeTrigger I have this error:
**Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor.**

I use a host builder:

```
public static async Task Main()
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();

            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }

        static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() => new HostBuilder()
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
            {
                configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                configHost.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
                configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
            {
                var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
                configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                configApp.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: !env.IsProduction());
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
               [...]
            })
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterModule<MessagerModule>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
            {
                if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    configLogging.AddConsole();
                    configLogging.AddDebug();
                }
            })
            .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

and here is the function:

```
[Function("QueueMessage")]
        public async Task QueueMessageAsync(
            [TimerTrigger("%MessageQueuerOccurence%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer
        )
        {
           [...]
        }
```

csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="**\*.json" Exclude="bin\**\*;obj\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.20.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

local.settings.json:

> {
> "IsEncrypted": false,
> "Values": {
> "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
> "MessageQueuerOccurence": "0 */15 * * * *",
> "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
> }
> }

What did I miss?

note: link to Github : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/779

Comment: Are you getting this error locally or after deployment in Azure?

Comment: Hi, I have this error locally.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was having this issue because I didn't have the storage emulator running...

It worked once I installed and ran `azurite`, which is the storage emulator that is being maintained (`Azure Storage Emulator` has been discontinued). You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code) on how to install it and use it.

I am using VS Code on a Mac OS, and I found the simplest solution to install `azurite` extension on VS Code. After the installation, I just had to edit the extension settings, in order to set the `location` setting (any folder should work). After that I was able to start `azurite` by running the `Azurite: Start` from the VS Code command palette.

---

As per the comments, it might also be necessary to edit the `local.settings.json` file and change the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) The storage emulator is already running, what I found is when I delete the appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json, the issue disapears. I added this comment to github, as it's a preview version, maybe there is something not well configured ...

Comment: avec plaisir! I am not using any of those files on my setup, btw

Comment: On top of that, I also had to edit the `local.settings.json` file and change the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value to `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`. HTH :)

Comment: thanks for posting this, but why do we even need this? What does blob storage have to do with a timer function??

Comment: @d512 every function app requires a storage account to operate.

Answer (score 5):

Im using .net7 (Azure.Functions.Worker)

Inside your **local.settings.json** file make sure to specify the key '**AzureWebJobsStorage**'

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had nested objects inside the local.settings.json, and so the AzureWebJobsStorage was not being recognized correctly. Fixing that solved the issue

Comment: In my case, I need to use "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain but I think this issue started for me once I updated visual studio.
So I've been trying to sort this out for 2 days. I tried many different things:

- Installed latest windows update
- Delete previous versions of Visual Studio i.e. 2019
- Updated Visual Studio 2022
- Deleted Visual Studio 2022
- Installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview
- Reinstalled Azurite extension in VS Code and set location to ..AppData/Temp
- Deleted and re-cloned my repo.
- Cleaned and rebuilt code.
- Deleted the azurite db files
- Deleted the whole azure folder in AppData/Temp
- Manually ran Azurite in powershell
- Ran Azurite in VS Code
- Reinstalled Azurite extension in VS Code

Nothing seemed to work.
I then realised that I forgot to do the obvious...

> DELETE THE OBJ AND BIN FOLDERS

After doing that it worked.

Now what doesn't make sense is that after re-cloning the repo it is basically deleting the bin and obj folders.

So I don't think that's the only reason why things worked.

Prior to deleting the obj and bin folders I also tried:

- making sure all services listening on ports 10000, 10001, 10002 were stopped.
- ran Azurite in Powershell from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator`
- Opened Azure Storage Explorer and created dummy container called 'test'
- Used the actual connection string (`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=https://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=https://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=https://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;`) for the Azurite emulator instance in the `local.settings.json` file instead of `UseDevelopmentStorage=true`

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same exact issue - `local.settings.json` was correct, local Azurite was running, just needed to delete `bin` and `obj` directories.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the FunctionName [FunctionName("Email")] was not the same as the classname Nip.cs in the root.

When changing the FunctionName to Nip it all worked again.