# TimerTrigger Azure Function won't work no matter what I do

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

Whenever I create a TimerTrigger Azure Function, I get this error

***Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor.***

This happens no matter what I do. I am using .NET without changing the default code provided when creating the function. I've also tried creating the function locally and publishing it from Visual Studio to Azure and the deploy worked but still, I encounter this error. I also have a free trial Azure account. I've looked upon the internet but couldn't find anything, maybe it's something regarding the configuration of the account? Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: hi, you found this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764836/timetrigger-exception-could-not-create-blobcontainerclient-for-schedulemonitor

Comment: hi, yeah I did but I don't think it can help me in any way, locally when I created the function it worked fine, but on Azure it didn't. I've tried creating HttpTrigger functions on Azure and they worked but the Timer one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the file "status" inside the container `azure-webjobs-hosts` contains the schedule which is to be performed by the timer trigger function. If this file is missing or unavailable, you will get the error message `Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor`.

[image]

In order to make this work make sure you have `AzureWebJobsStorage` configured in your Azure function by navigating to your **Function App >> Configuration >> `AzureWebJobsStorage`** with the connection string of your storage account.

[image]